# Livecode: Two different button functions depending if clicked before

Tags: button, livecode

In Livecode, I'm trying to get a button working with a "connect"/"disconnect" function. How can I get the button to know if it's already been clicked before, executing code A and then, when clicked again, should execute code B? The button needs to be clicked several times between "connected" and "disconnected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a standard button and you only have 2 states (disconnected/connected), an easy way is to disable the autoHilite property of the button and manually set the button's hilite in its script:

```
on mouseUp
   set the hilite of me to not the hilite of me
   if the hilite of me then
       -- do connecting stuff here
   else
       -- do disconnecting stuff here
   end if
end mouseUp
```

You don't explain why the button needs to be clicked multiple times, but assuming you need more than two connection states, you can use a custom property to store the current state.  As an example, you could use values of 'empty' (disconnected), 'handshaking' (starting the process), 'connecting' (in process), and 'linked' (connected) for each state.  Something like:

```
# STORE CURRENT CONNECTING STATE IN connectionState

on mouseUp
   switch the connectionState of me
      case empty
         -- start connection process, show HANDSHAKING feedback here
         hilite me
         set the connectionState of me to "handshaking"
      break
      case "handshaking"
         -- if initial handshake successful, begin connecting to system
         if handShakeSuccessful is true then
             -- start connection process, show CONNECTING feedback here
             set the connectionState of me to "connecting"
         end if
      break
      case "connecting"
         -- if initial connection is successful, show LINKED feedback here
         if connectionSuccessful is true then
            set the connectionState of me to "linked"
         end if
      break
      case "linked"
         -- do disconnecting stuff here
         set the connectionState of me to empty
         unhilite me
   end switch
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Well, I have to admit that my description was a bit unclear (the result of less sleep time last night...). Regarding the multiple click button, the button needs the two different states (on/off) for connection between the client (the LiveCode application) and the graphic/play-out server. The server is using a simple text protocol so there's no need for handshake. The graphics operator must be able to connect and disconnect during the use if the server needs a reboot. Therefore, the button needs to know if it's already connected och disconnected.

Comment: The #1 solution works great, but I'm just curious if there's another solution where you don't need the hilite workaround.

Comment: You can set the label of the button to whatever you want, as mentioned above (the button's label is independent of its name).  The label can act as a toggle or state indicator: if the label of me is "Disconnected" then <do connection stuff>, set the label of me to "Connected".  And vice versa.  Or you can use a custom property as mentioned in the example, something like: set the isConnected of me to true (or false).  Using the button's hilite is just another visual indicator to show a difference in state.

Answer (score 0):

In the ChatRev stack, we use the label of the button to indicate its status.

```
if the label of me is "Connect" then
  set the label of me to "Disconnect"
  open socket gSocket
  write "helo" & cr to socket gSocket
  read from socket gSocket with message "connected"
else // "Disconnect"
  set the label of me to "Connect"
  write "disconnect" to socket gSocket
  repeat for each line myLine in the openSockets
    close socket myLine
  end repeat
end if
```

If the label is "Connected" the connection should be closed and if the label is "Connect" the connection should be established.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use setProp handlers in situations like this. The button is used only as a "toggle" switch.

```
# the button script
on mouseUp
   set the uConnectedState of this cd to not the uConnectedState of this cd
end mouseUp

# in the card script (or wherever appropriate)
setProp uConnectedState pIsConnected
   if pIsConnected then
      set the label of btn "connect" to "Disconnect"
      # any other interface updates or logic here
   else
      set the label of btn "connect" to "Connect"
      # any other interface updates or logic here
   end if
   pass uConnectedState
end uConnectedState
```

Doing it this way means all I have to do is set the custom property and all of the business is handled by the setProp handler. For example, if I need to initialize the connection on openCard all I have to do is set the uConnectedState of the card to false/true.